# JPA - How to avoid tight coupling and redundancy?

Tags: java, oop, jpa, tightly-coupled-code

(Still studying now and then the OO principles to get a better understanding of OOP.)

Three (JPA) entities have the following has-a relation:

**A** has a collection of **B** and **B** has a field 'a' pointing to **A** (bidirectional relation)
**B** has a collection of **C** and **C** has a field 'b' pointing to B (bidirectional relation)

(I would say by using JPA you get tight coupling for free. Which is not so great of course.)

**A**, **B** and **C** have a field 'nr'. Those fields together form a id divided by dots. Something like this: ####.####.####

Now I would like to ask **A** to build that number. What is the proper way to do that following the OO-principles? In my opinion **C** should not have any knowledge of **B** and **B** not of **A**.

Comment: Question is probably better suited for [Programmers SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Didn't know of the existence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say this is a new class **ID** with a constructor **ID(A a, B b, C c)**.

Depending on the real meaning of your objects it may be appropriate to give **A** the responsibility of creating these if you wish but clearly - as you point out - its should not be done by **B** or **C**.

i.e.

```
class A {
  ID newID(B b, C c) {
    return new ID(this, b, c);
  }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't be it     "class A {...}" instead of     "class B {...}"? (Thanks for answering. I didn't thought of introducing a new class (ID) for this problem before.)

Comment: @Barthelomeus - You are right - it should have been **A** - changed.